# How to fix "No Such Method Error" RichTextFx Java

Tags: java, javafx, richtextfx

I am using an external jar *richtextfx 06.10* in my project with jdk12, javafx12

I tried to use latest release of *richtextfx* but didn't work
I got this error:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.fxmisc.richtext.skin.TextExt.impl_selectionFillProperty()Ljavafx/b
>
> eans/property/ObjectProperty

Comment: You should show the code which is producing that error.

Comment: My guess is the version of RichTextFX you're using is not compatible with JavaFX 9+ (which is not unsurprising, since it appears to be using internal code). What happens when you try the [latest version](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/releases/tag/v0.10.1)?

Comment: When I remove 6.10 and add 10.1  I couldn't import these                          
import org.fxmisc.richtext.PopupAlignment;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.StyleSpans;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.StyleSpansBuilder;

Comment: [here is my class which gives error](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gnDHTZHPPb/)